# How to convert null to string in aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My collection Looks like this:

```
[
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "638ecf5247cf747bdd862bfb"
  },
  "title": "This is title one"
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "638ecf5247cf747bdd862bfb"
  },
  "title": null
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "638ecf5247cf747bdd862bfb"
  },
  "title": "This is title three"
}
]
```

But I want to convert every title that have null to string (not-found):

```
[
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "638ecf5247cf747bdd862bfb"
  },
  "title": "This is title one"
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "638ecf5247cf747bdd862bfb"
  },
  "title": "not-found" // null to be converted to string
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "638ecf5247cf747bdd862bfb"
  },
  "title": "This is title three"
}
]
```

How to convert null title to string for all documents that have null title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple update:

```
db.collection.updateMany({
  "title": null
},
{
  $set: {
    title: "not-found"
  }
})
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SNTezosI61e)

Comment: You'll need to set `{multi:true}` for all docs.

Comment: Only if you use `update` instead of `updateMany`

Comment: Good point! But your playground example won't use `updateMany`. I'm enjoying this speed game!

Answer (score 2):

3 things:

- Filter the items that you want to update `{title:null}`
- [$set](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) the update to change the field value
- Ensure that you can update multiple documents

Playground - https://mongoplayground.net/p/DfAWE1Swszb

```
db.collection.update({
  title: null
},
{
  $set: {
    title: "not-found"
  }
},
{
  multi: true
})
```